# How to check that state is set to a new value when setter receives a callback that returns a value rather than the value itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

When we have

```js
function ParentComponent() {
   const [state, setState] = useState({
     name: 'Rob',
     age: '55'
   });

   return <ChildComponent state={state} setState={setState} />;
}
```

and inside `ChildComponent` something like this happens:

```
setState({
  name: 'Alice',
  age: 44
});
```

we can do

```
const mockSetter = jest.fn();

render(<ChildComponent state={{ name: 'Rob', age: 55 }} setState={mockSetter} />);

// interact with ChildComponent to make it call `setState`

expect(mockSetter).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  name: 'Alice',
  age: 55
});
```

But how do I test that the new state has been set to `{ name: 'Alice', age: 55 }` in case the `setState` prop inside `ChildComponent` is called with a function instead of an object? For example:

```
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, name: 'Alice' })
```

In this case `mockSetter` will be called with a function so my original `toHaveBeenCalledWith` check is no longer valid. It expects an object `{ name: 'Alice', age: 55 }` but gets a function `prevState => ({ ...prevState, name: 'Alice' }`.

How do I check that the `state` has been set to `{ name: 'Alice', age: 55 }` after a `ChildComponent` interaction (even though I don't have the `state` variable to refer to in my tests)?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be passing around `setState` anyway, the parent loses all control of its state that way. Do the merge _in the parent_, then the original test for the child continues to pass. (Assuming you _have_ two components, that's not entirely clear from the question.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, but it is what it is for now. So the question stands. Yes, I have a parent component that defines some state getter and setter and passes the setter to a child component (MyComp, in this case).

Comment: So think about what you _do_ expect it to get called with. Not an object, but a function that _takes_ an object and returns the right result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, sorry, I guess I should have made myself more clear. I want to check that the derived state the callback passed to `setState` produces matches the object I'm expecting. I will update my question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It's not clear what's stopping you from just _calling that function_ and finding out what it returns.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because `mockSetter` will be called as `setState` from inside `MyComp`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247374/discussion-between-vitaly-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, mock setter function of the `useState` hook will break the real implementation of it. Your test may pass based on the mock setter function, but the actual code may not run correctly.

But if you insist to do so, you can use `jest.fn().mockImplementation()` to create mock implementation for the setter function of `useState`. (**Not recommended!! React doesn't know how to update the state anymore with this mock setter function!**)

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const ChildComponent = ({ state, setState }) => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, name: 'Alice' }));
      }}
    >
      ChildComponent
    </div>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { ChildComponent } from './';

describe('73406702', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const prevState = { name: 'Rob', age: 55 };
    let nextState;
    const mockSetter = jest.fn().mockImplementation((callback) => {
      nextState = callback(prevState);
    });
    render(<ChildComponent state={prevState} setState={mockSetter} />);
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/ChildComponent/));
    expect(nextState).toEqual({ name: 'Alice', age: 55 });
  });
});
```

We can provide `prevState` by ourselves, and get the `nextState`.

This mock implementation is only used for testing the state merging logic `{ ...prevState, name: 'Alice' }`. React doesn't know how to update the state and re-render the component anymore with this mock setter function. Because we didn't provide this feature for the mock setter function. The real implementation of the setter function is complicated.

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73406702/index.test.tsx (10.451 s)
  73406702
    ✓ should pass (28 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.948 s, estimated 12 s
```

In the end, the testing philosophy for react component, or, any UI component is to test the component behavior stand from the user's perspective. You can think it's black-box testing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a parent and child that actually do something that we can test, some visible change when the state updates:

```
// ParentComponent.js
import { useState } from "react";

import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

function ParentComponent() {

    const [state, setState] = useState({ name: "Rob", age: 55 });

    return (
        <ChildComponent state={state} setState={setState} />
    );
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

```
// ChildComponent.js
function ChildComponent({ state, setState }) {

    const handleClick = () => {
        setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, name: "Alice" }));
    };

    return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me, {state.name}!</button>;
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Right now they are *heavily* coupled, with the child having to "know" all about its parent's state, so putting a testing boundary between them isn't really appropriate.

There are three ways of testing this:

1. If you really must keep the current implementation, and still want to test the child independently despite the coupling, think about the *actual responsibility* of the child. It's to call the setter callback with a function that, given an existing state, returns an updated state. So that's the *behaviour* the test should reflect:

   ```
   // ChildComponent.test.js
   import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
   import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

   import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

   describe("ChildComponent", () => {
       it("provides a state updater on click", async () => {
           const mockSetter = jest.fn();
           const existing = { name: "Rob", age: 55 };
           render(<ChildComponent state={existing} setState={mockSetter} />);

           await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Click me, Rob!" }));

           expect(mockSetter).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
           const [updater] = mockSetter.mock.lastCall;
           const updated = updater(existing);
           expect(updated).toEqual({ name: "Alice", age: 55 });
           expect(updated).not.toBe(existing);  // ensure it didn't just mutate the input
       });
   });
   ```

   This test seems relatively complicated for such a simple component, which should serve to highlight the problem - elements of this boundary belong to React's API, not ours.
2. Reflect the coupling by testing the `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent` as one unit, so the real state is being used and updated:

   ```
   // ParentComponent.test.js
   import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
   import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

   import ParentComponent from "./ParentComponent";

   describe("ParentComponent", () => {
       it("does the whole thing", async () => {
           render(<ParentComponent/>);

           await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Click me, Rob!" }));

           expect(screen.getByRole("button")).toHaveTextContent("Click me, Alice!");
       });
   });
   ```

   You could also reflect this coupling by not exposing the child to the outside world, either by moving it into the same file as the parent or having a directory-based module that *only* exposes the parent:

   ```bash
   /module
       ChildComponent.js
       index.js  # export { default } from "./ParentComponent";
       ParentComponent.js
   ```
3. Decouple the components by hoisting the state merging up to the parent, so all the child does is e.g.:

   ```
   // ChildComponent.js
   // ...
   const handleClick = () => setState("Alice");
   ```

   and the parent is responsible for updating its own state based on that:

   ```
   // ParentComponent.js
   // ...
   return (
       <ChildComponent
           state={state}
           setState={(name) => setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, name }))}
       />
   );
   ```

   Now the child is trivial to test, because you're back to asserting on a simple value (and the test above for the parent and child together will pass throughout this refactor):

   ```
   // ChildComponent.test.js
   // ...
   expect(mockSetter).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Alice");
   ```